# What does the Ubuntu Pictogram Mousemat and Coaster Sets Look Like In Real Life?

Tags: 12.04

My question is regrading to the Ubuntu Pictogram Mousemat and Coaster Sets on the Ubuntu Website! Can you please send me some details about this product! I am purchasing the desktop and server version! But I was not very please with the Ubuntu Mouse, do to the size issue! It did not fit the standard hand palm! The mouse is a traveling mouse/mini mouse! So can you please send me some photo's what they look like. Because I have a feeling there will be flaws with the product?
[ https://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?currency=USD&products_id=1117&sort=1a ]
Thank You
RM3

Answer (score 1):

From the link:

- Mouse mat is 19 x 24 cm
- Coaster is 9 cm

That should give enough information on how large these 2 are?

In case you need imperial:

- Mouse mat is 7.4 x 9.4 inch
- Coaster is 3.54 inch

That should give you an idea of the sizes (or you can compare it to something in your househole; all you need is a ruler).

---

For reference: mouse mat and coasters next to a coffee cup:

[image]

Might be cropped though :D The mouse mat is a normal size one (the 2 I have here are about the size listed above).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, after you spill coffee on it and use it a lot:

[image]

(not actual size)